# Typescript: cannot access static fields across packges

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a **package A** which is a dependency of **package B**.

In **pkg A**, I have a class-based enum defined to serve certain purpose:

```
export class Stage {
  readonly name: string;

  public static readonly PROD: Stage = new Stage('Prod');
  public static readonly BETA: Stage = new Stage('Beta');
  private constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static fromName(name: string) {
    if (name == 'Prod') return Stage.PROD;
    if (name == 'Beta') return Stage.BETA;
    return null;
  }
}
```

In **pkg B**, directly access the static field will throw up errors:

```
import {Stage} from "pkg-a";

const beta: Stage = Stage.fromName("Beta"); // OK
const prod: Stage = Stage.PROD; // TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROD' of undefined
```

I have also looked into the compiled JS code of the `Stage` class in the `node_modules`. And seems like it did export those static fields:

```
// tsc compiled js file
class Stage {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
exports.Stage = Stage;
Stage.BETA = new Stage("Beta");
Stage.PROD = new Stage("Prod");
```

I don't know why I am still getting errors like this.

Does anyone happen to have experience about this issue?

Comment: I got two other TypeScript errors. The first in `const beta: Stage = Stage.fromName("Beta");` because `Stage.fromName` returns `Stage | null` and the second in `private constructor(name){` because `name` has implicitly `any` type. After I fixed it, the code works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-krljdj?file=pkg-b/index.ts Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @jabaa, those are typos and thank you for your tryout. I am working on a minimal reproducible example.